# Jackson, how to properly write a custom deserializer

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson2

I'm trying to migrate from Gson to Jackson, but I'm encountering many difficulties because I don't quite understand how to deserialize a complex JSON.
The file looks like this:

```json
{
    "data_type": "DatType1",
    "data": {
        "data_array": [
            {
                "data_type": "DataType2",
                "data": {
                    "prop1": "AString",
                    "prop2": ALongValue,
                    "prop3": null,
                    "prop4": "AString",
                }
            },
            {
                "data_type": "DataType2",
                "data": {
                    "prop1": "AString",
                    "prop2": ALongValue,
                    "prop3": "AString",
                    "prop4": null,
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I tried to write this custom deserializer:

```java
public class DataListDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<DataList> {

    public DataListDeserializer() {
        this(null);
    }

    public DataListDeserializer(Class<?> vc) {
        super(vc);
    }

    @Override
    public DataList deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext context) throws IOException {
        JsonNode node = parser.getCodec().readTree(parser);

        DataTypeEnum type = DataTypeEnum.from(node.get("data_type").asText());
        JsonNode dataNode = node.get("data");

        JsonParser ps = dataNode.findValue("data_array").traverse();
        ps.setCodec(parser.getCodec());
        List<Data2> trophies = ps.readValueAs(new TypeReference<List<Data2>>() {});
        return null; // Ignore null I'm using the debugger to check
    }
}
```

But the deserialized Data2 objects have all fields `null`
Plus, at the end I should build a DataList object with the parsed type and Data2 list, but I can't use a constructor because I need it to be private, the object is immutable.
How can I do it?

Note:
With Gson I didn't write any deserializer because I was using JsonPath to get nested objects. I was using this TyepAdapterFactory with a custom annotation:

```java
public final class JsonPathTypeAdapterFactory implements TypeAdapterFactory {
    //================================================================================
    // Properties
    //================================================================================
    private static final TypeAdapterFactory jsonPathTypeAdapterFactory = new JsonPathTypeAdapterFactory();

    //================================================================================
    // Constructors
    //================================================================================
    private JsonPathTypeAdapterFactory() {
    }

    //================================================================================
    // Getters
    //================================================================================
    public static TypeAdapterFactory getJsonPathTypeAdapterFactory() {
        return jsonPathTypeAdapterFactory;
    }

    //================================================================================
    // Override Methods
    //================================================================================
    @Override
    public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(final Gson gson, final TypeToken<T> typeToken) {
        final TypeAdapter<T> delegateAdapter = gson.getDelegateAdapter(this, typeToken);
        final Collection<FieldInfo> fieldInfos = FieldInfo.of(new ArrayList<>(), typeToken.getRawType());
        return fieldInfos.isEmpty() ? delegateAdapter : new JsonPathTypeAdapter<>(gson, delegateAdapter, gson.getAdapter(JsonElement.class), fieldInfos);
    }

    //================================================================================
    // Nested Classes
    //================================================================================
    private static final class JsonPathTypeAdapter<T> extends TypeAdapter<T> {
        private final Gson gson;
        private final TypeAdapter<T> delegateAdapter;
        private final TypeAdapter<JsonElement> jsonElementTypeAdapter;
        private final Collection<FieldInfo> fieldInfos;

        private JsonPathTypeAdapter(final Gson gson, final TypeAdapter<T> delegateAdapter, final TypeAdapter<JsonElement> jsonElementTypeAdapter, final Collection<FieldInfo> fieldInfos) {
            this.gson = gson;
            this.delegateAdapter = delegateAdapter;
            this.jsonElementTypeAdapter = jsonElementTypeAdapter;
            this.fieldInfos = fieldInfos;
        }

        @Override
        public void write(final JsonWriter out, final T value) throws IOException {
            delegateAdapter.write(out, value);
        }

        @Override
        public T read(final JsonReader in) throws IOException {
            final JsonElement outerJsonElement = jsonElementTypeAdapter.read(in).getAsJsonObject();
            final T value = delegateAdapter.fromJsonTree(outerJsonElement);
            for (final FieldInfo fieldInfo : fieldInfos) {
                try {
                    final JsonElement innerJsonElement = fieldInfo.jsonPath.read(outerJsonElement);
                    final Object innerValue = gson.fromJson(innerJsonElement, fieldInfo.field.getType());
                    fieldInfo.field.set(value, innerValue);
                } catch (final PathNotFoundException ignored) {
                } catch (final IllegalAccessException ex) {
                    throw new IOException(ex);
                }
            }
            return value;
        }

    }

    private static final class FieldInfo {
        private final Field field;
        private final JsonPath jsonPath;

        private FieldInfo(final Field field, final JsonPath jsonPath) {
            this.field = field;
            this.jsonPath = jsonPath;
        }

        private static Collection<FieldInfo> of(Collection<FieldInfo> fieldInfo, Class<?> clazz) {
            fieldInfo.addAll(
                    Arrays.stream(clazz.getDeclaredFields())
                            .filter(f -> f.getAnnotation(JsonPathExpression.class) != null)
                            .map(f -> {
                                final JsonPathExpression jsonPathExpression = f.getAnnotation(JsonPathExpression.class);
                                f.setAccessible(true);
                                return new FieldInfo(f, compile(jsonPathExpression.value()));
                            })
                            .collect(Collectors.toList())
            );

            if (clazz.getSuperclass() != null) {
                of(fieldInfo, clazz.getSuperclass());
            }

            return fieldInfo;
        }
    }
}
```

It was very good actually, very easy, but I don't think there's a way to make it work with Jackson too, isn't it?

Comment: Have you tried mapping your JSON to POJOs instead of using a custom deserializer?

Comment: Did you figure this out? I am also in the same boat and would appreciate your fidnings

Comment: @VimalKumar unfortunately no. At the time I was having trouble with Gson becase there was a nasty "bug" when handling Long values. Several months later it got fixed, in the meanwhile though my conclusion was that using Gson is much simpler, even writing adapters is much easier and there are plenty of crystal clear guides, can't say the same for Jackson

Comment: No worries. I figured out TypeAdapterFactories are more for serialization/deserialization in one package. In our TypeAdapterFactories, we deserialized the current json to object, and then updated few fields on the object. I achieved this with JsonCreator annotation on a method and JsonProperty on method fields, to deserialize and then create the final object and return the object. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sharing a code snippet for implementing custom Deserializer 
Basically here we are stopping the user to enter decimal point for integer type for rest api call --->>
    
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonDeserializer;
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
    
    import java.io.IOException;
    
    public class CustomIntegerDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Integer> {
    
        private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomIntegerDeserializer.class);
    
        @Override
        public Integer deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctx)
             throws IOException,JsonProcessingException {
            logger.info("CustomIntegerDeserializer..............................");
            Double doubleVal = p.getDoubleValue();
            try {
                double ceil = Math.ceil(doubleVal);
                double floor = Math.floor(doubleVal);
                if((ceil-floor)>0) {
                    String message = String.format("Cannot coerce a floating-point value ('%s') into Integer", doubleVal.toString());
                    throw new Exception(message);
                }
                return Integer.valueOf(p.getIntValue());
            } catch (Exception exception) {
                logger.info("Exception in CustomIntegerDeserializer::{}",exception.getMessage());
          
                //throw new custom exception which are to be managed by exception handler
                
            }
        }
    
    }

   
    using on bean class-->
     @JsonDeserialize(using = CustomIntegerDeserializer.class)
        private Integer initRatePerSec = -1;

    request-->
    {
        .....
        "initRatePerSec": 5.1
    }
    response-->
    {
        "statusCode": 400,
         ..............,
        "message": "JSON parse error: Cannot coerce a floating-point value ('5.1') into Integer; 
    }
```